# Why is the sleep function being executed before anything?

Tags: c, sleep

When i execute the code below the sleep function executes before both print statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

  printf("before\n");

  sleep(4);

  printf("after");

  return 0;

}
```

So instead of: `before -> *waits 4 seconds* -> after`
It performs: `*waits 4 seconds* -> before -> after`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this -- I get the expected behavior if I run it in a terminal. Are you redirecting the output to a file (this would cause block buffering as opposed to line buffering)?

Comment: It's giving the right order for me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what environment you are running your C program in, sometimes the output of `printf` goes into a large buffer instead of directly going to your screen.  Try flushing that buffer by putting the following line directly after each line that calls `printf`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked great